# How do you remove HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, spree

I installed haml 2.2 on a Spree application with

```
rake gems:install
```

After placing it in my environment.rb .

Just like I thought, nothing loads anymore. Spree seems to be very exclusive about their source code.

Does anyone know anyway I can delete haml and restore my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your config/environment.rb. If you see:

`config.gem haml`

remove that line.

Comment: Yah.. did that. Its still loading a blank screen.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that was a "no no" with Spree to install haml.

Comment: If you simply added the `config.gem` to your environment.rb, then taking it out should reverse the effect even though the Haml gem is installed on your system. What do the logs tell you about why the page is blank?

Comment: Thanks Steve. That actually fixed it, and the other issue I was having was related to something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that HAML is not in environment.rb anymore, check that it's not installed as a plugin in vendor/plugins and finally uninstall the gem (sudo gem uninstall haml).